# Trying to get my kali linux to recognize my asus ac53 nano wireless adaptor

Tags: apt, wifi, kali-linux

Hey everyone like the title says I'm trying to get wi-fi working on my new kali install. I was able to tether my phone to it so I've already done `sudo apt update` and added more sources to my `sources.list` file. Any other help i can get would be appreciated!

```
razanumberone㉿Raza)-[~]
└─$ uname -r                                                                                                  1 ⨯
5.10.0-kali3-amd64
                                                                                                                   
┌──(razanumberone㉿Raza)-[~]
└─$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9070 (network tethering, USB debugging enabled)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1b80:b510 Afatech USB Gaming Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:184c ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 18f8:0f99 [Maxxter] Optical gaming mouse
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:02ea Microsoft Corp. Xbox One S Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                                                                                                                   
┌──(razanumberone㉿Raza)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt-get install kali-linux-wireless                                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython2.7-stdlib : Breaks: python-numpy (< 1:1.12.1-3.1) but 1:1.6.2-1.2 is to be installed
 mariadb-client-10.3 : Conflicts: virtual-mysql-client
                       Breaks: mysql-client-5.5 but 5.5.40-0+wheezy1 is to be installed
 mariadb-client-core-10.3 : Conflicts: mysql-client-5.5 but 5.5.40-0+wheezy1 is to be installed
 mariadb-server-core-10.3 : Conflicts: mysql-server-5.5 but 5.5.40-0+wheezy1 is to be installed
                            Breaks: mysql-client-5.5 but 5.5.40-0+wheezy1 is to be installed
                            Breaks: mysql-server-core-5.5 but 5.5.40-0+wheezy1 is to be installed
 mysql-common : Conflicts: mysql-server-5.5 but 5.5.40-0+wheezy1 is to be installed
 python-is-python2 : Breaks: python-minimal but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed
 python2-minimal : Breaks: python-minimal (< 2.7.15-2) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed
 tcl : Breaks: tcl8.5 (< 8.5.14-3) but 8.5.11-2 is to be installed
 tk : Breaks: tk8.5 (< 8.5.14-3) but 8.5.11-2 is to be installed
 wifitap : Depends: python-scapy but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

┌──(razanumberone㉿Raza)-[~]
└─$
```

Answer (score 0):

#### solving broken `apt`

apt is broken because you have mixed [kali repository](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/) with debian wheezy repo. To solve this problem:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

#### getting the wireless working.

clone the [`jeremyb31/rtl8822bu`](https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8822bu/) repository:

> A few known wireless cards that use this driver include
>
> - Edimax EW-7822ULC
> - **ASUS AC-53 NANO**

> NOTE: At least v4.7 is needed to compile this module sorry people with older kernels, the code is removed. Upon request I can work towards making it backwards compatible.

```
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8822bu.git
cd rtl8822bu
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -v 8822bu
lsmod |grep 8822bu
```

Comment: So I did as you said in the first half. It did some updates and i restarted just to be safe. and then i ran the commands again and it says 0 upgraded, installed, ect. When it comes to installing the driver I was trying this one before but it wasn't working. Now when i try it after the update i get this:

Comment: `┌──(razanumberone㉿Raza)-[~/Desktop/utilities/wireless-driver/asus-ac53-rtl8822bu-master]
└─$ make
/bin/sh: 1: bc: not found
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.10.0-kali3-amd64/build M=/home/razanumberone/Desktop/utilities/wireless-driver/asus-ac53-rtl8822bu-master  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.10.0-kali3-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:1986: modules] Error 2`

Comment: i tried it both with cloning and by just cd into the masterfile